# Bootstrap pgwslideshow for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

thanks for taking a look.

I've been playing with a bootstrap slideshow called pgwSlideshow, and I have it almost to a point of contentment, but I am not quite there because of how one element renders on a mobile device. On a mobile device, the forward and backward arrow keys, which go to the next or previous the image, are on top of the image. I would like to either have them be on the sides of the image, as they are on a laptop/desktop, or gone completely.

I tried to do some specific css @media stuff, but it didn't seem to pick up. I know that the command for this in JS is displayControls: false - but I can't figure out how to target this to a mobile device and see it work. Please find below an example in codepen. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Please let me know if more information would be useful

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waqaQp

```
.slides {
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The above is what I do for the desktop version, but it doesn't fix the next and previous arrows from landing on top of the image on a mobile version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I don't know how to delete this thing, but this is what I did:

I added to the head in the html of the page:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then for the javascript, and if/else statement with a width specification:

```
if ( $(window).width() > 739) {  
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.pgwSlideshow').pgwSlideshow({
  autoSlide: false,
  maxHeight: 800
});
});
}
else {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.pgwSlideshow').pgwSlideshow({
  autoSlide: false,
  displayControls: false
});
});
}
```